# Remove a particular line containing a number from a text file

Tags: text-processing

I have a .csv file having several lines of data.
I have to search for a particular value in the string/record  and delete that line itself.

For example:

abc.csv

```
col1_id,col2,col3,col4,col5
1000541,aaaa,bbbb,cccc,dddd
1000542,eeee,ffff,gggg,hhhh
1000543,iiii,jjjj,kkkk,llll
1000544,mmmm,nnnn,oooo,pppp
```

I need to search for 1000542 and remove the whole line containing that number:

```
col1_id,col2,col3,col4,col5
1000541,aaaa,bbbb,cccc,dddd
1000543,iiii,jjjj,kkkk,llll
1000544,mmmm,nnnn,oooo,pppp
```

Comment: `grep -v 1000542`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sed` to remove one line:

```
sed -i '/1000542/d' abc.cvs
```

where `d` removes the line, `-i` tells `sed` to operate on the file rather than just output the modified text, `1000542` is the pattern you want to search for and `abc.cvs` is the filename.

Comment: It's `d` that removes the line. `-i` is a GNU extension that's for in-place editing (making `sed` a text file editor instead of a stream editor). With the `sed` of recent BSDs you need `-i ''` instead. Portably, you can use `ed` or `perl`.

Comment: Sorry, the description wasn't clear enough. I edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use awk also,

```
awk '/1000542/ {next}1' infile > outfile
```

**Example:**

```
$ awk '/1000542/ {next}1' file
col1_id,col2,col3,col4,col5
1000541,aaaa,bbbb,cccc,dddd
1000543,iiii,jjjj,kkkk,llll
1000544,mmmm,nnnn,oooo,pppp
```

It skips the line which contains `1000542` from printing.

Comment: Why not simply `awk '!/1000542/'` or `grep -v 1000542`?

Comment: There are more number of possiblities for an text processing question :-)